# Как пользоваться БД нескольким пользователям?

Tags: mysql, база-данных, windows, сервер, mysql-workbench

Использую ***windows 10*** и ***mysql***. Я новичок в этом деле. У меня есть база данных в mysql. Я бы хотел, чтобы ей пользовался еще другой человек. Добавлял и изменял данные. Как он может подключиться ко мне? Можно какой-нибудь гайд

Comment: серверная машина должна быть доступна по сети, разрешить входящие в фаерволе, разрешить удаленные подключения для учетки юзера

Comment: а после этого пользователю остается прописать в консоль подключение - mysql -u root -h 82.202.199.34 -p, верно? Еще через ISPmanager как-то можно настроить или я не о том говорю?

Comment: @JameTime, да, он может использовать любой клиент для доступа к СУБД, проблема заключается исключительно в том, чтобы расшарить доступ к Вашему пк во всемирной сети. Желательно ему ещё и учетку в СУБД отдельную сделать.

Comment: @SergeyK. Понял, спасибо.

Comment: у вас сервер то где? на вашей машине под виндой, или на хостинге с ISPManager ? Откуда вы вообще этот ispmanager вытащили?

Comment: @teran На моем пк. Я просто искал способы, чтобы можно вдвоем пользоваться бд. ispmanager как один из вариантов, который я находил